# Ubuntu hang with no video signal on Blender and Krita

Tags: video

I have the issue with the computer. When I use software such as Krita or Blender the system hang happens. The video signal is off but the audio could heard for some time. This situation happens with the Ubuntu 20.04 as well as with my currently installed Ubuntu 22.04, both for nvidia-driver-470 and Nouveau driver.

Could you let me know the approach to troubleshoot the issue.

My configuration is as follow:

```
cpu:
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz, 4183 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz, 1600 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz, 4166 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz, 4183 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz, 4184 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz, 4117 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz, 4180 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz, 4180 MHz
keyboard:
  /dev/input/event5    Gaming KB
mouse:
  /dev/input/mice      Holtek E-Signal LUOM G10 Mechanical Gaming Mouse
  /dev/input/mice      Wacom CTL-470 [Bamboo Connect]
  /dev/input/mice      Wacom CTL-470 [Bamboo Connect]
monitor:
                       LG ELECTRONICS LG HDR WFHD
graphics card:
                       nVidia GK106 [GeForce GTX 660]
sound:
                       Intel 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
                       nVidia GK106 HDMI Audio Controller
storage:
                       Intel 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
network:
  enp3s0               Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
  enxf835dd39d6b9      Altair Modem YOTA 4G LTE
  wlx503eaaa6be52      Realtek RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
network interface:
  enp3s0               Ethernet network interface
  wlx503eaaa6be52      Ethernet network interface
  enxf835dd39d6b9      Ethernet network interface
  lo                   Loopback network interface
disk:
  /dev/sdb             ST1000DM010-2EP1
  /dev/sdc             ST2000DM001-9YN1
  /dev/sda             WDC WD60EFRX-68M
partition:
  /dev/sdb1            Partition
  /dev/sdc1            Partition
  /dev/sdc2            Partition
  /dev/sdc3            Partition
  /dev/sdc4            Partition
  /dev/sda1            Partition
usb controller:
                       Intel 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
                       Intel 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
                       Intel 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
bios:
                       BIOS
bridge:
                       Intel 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
                       Intel Z77 Express Chipset LPC Controller
                       Intel Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port
                       Intel 82801 PCI Bridge
                       Intel Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
                       Intel 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5
                       ASMedia ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge
hub:
                       Intel Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Intel Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
memory:
                       Main Memory
unknown:
                       FPU
                       DMA controller
                       PIC
                       Keyboard controller
                       Intel 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
                       Intel 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
                       Serial controller
  /dev/input/event3    Holtek E-Signal LUOM G10 Mechanical Gaming Mouse
                       Altair Modem YOTA 4G LTE
```

Comment: By borrowing GPU I have found out that the problem disappear, so I blame my video card for causing hang.